# encounter 'Broken pipe' error only while using step-by-step debug with GDB

Tags: xcode, sockets, gdb, boost-asio, broken-pipe

There is unix-socket server written on PHP (but I don't think it has something to with it). Client side is written on c++ and based on boost::asio library. When I launch program normally - everything **works fine**, except one (not related to socket communication) bug that I obviously want to debug. But when I start **step-by-step debugging** it I immediately receive **'Broken Pipe'** error on the steps which perform **write operations on sockets**. If breakpoint is set up after socket write operation - everything work fine until the next attempt to step over the write func.

Spent whole day trying to solve this problem, but unsuccessfully...

Had anyone met the same trouble?

- using GDB bundled with xCode 3.2.5 (64-bit) under OS X 10.6.7

Comment: The default behavior for `SIGPIPE` is to terminate the process, I suspect you are encountering a timing window that is perturbed by gdb.

Comment: Maybe so... But process receives `SIGABRT`instead of `SIGPIPE`. Also, I'm not sure if `boost::asio` is catching `SIGPIPE` to return an error corresponding to `EPIPE`

Comment: @ibadinov asio does not install signal handlers, your application should if the default behavior is not appropriate.

Comment: therefore `SIGABRT` is even more confusing

Comment: @Ibadinov I suggest you edit your question with more information. It's not obvious to me where `SIGABRT` is coming from, perhaps an uncaught exception.

Comment: Yes, you are right - `SIGABRT` was actually from uncaught... But still the question is what may cause the pipe to break during debug and work smoothly in normal conditions.

Answer (score 0):

`GDB` uses signals aggressively. If you want to install signal handlers, check out the following example:

https://github.com/sean-/Boost.Examples/blob/master/asio/timer/timer.cc#L106